# Why does image has that padding?

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying out to squeeze the columns into two while the page is xs size. I did the necessary logic, and also tried to implement the same with an using img. However while using an image, I'm unable to force the image to take the full size of the block. I've tried all necessary css editing and stuff, maybe I'm missing something please help. 
Take help of the jsfiddle link to understand it better. I've included the css in fiddle file
[Js Link](http://jsfiddle.net/z2b748o6/)!

```
<html>
<style>




</style>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid ">



             <div class="navbar-header ">
                 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left "  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                  </button>



            <form class="navbar-form pull-left  my-searchmain" role="search">
                <div class="input-group ">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control  " placeholder="Search">
                   <div class="input-group-btn">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                   </div>
                 </div>
            </form>




        </div>




    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <li class="active col-lg-1 col-xs-6 col-md-1 col-sm-1"><a href="#"><img id="imgnew" src="http://www.affordable-templates123.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/fancy-label-templates-nh8tgtgq.jpg" ></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown col-lg-1 col-xs-6 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 2 </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class=" col-lg-1 col-xs-6 col-md-1 col-sm-1"><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        <li class=" col-lg-1 col-xs-6 col-md-1 col-sm-1"><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
        <li class=" col-lg-1 col-xs-6 col-md-1 col-sm-1"><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
        <li class=" col-lg-1 col-xs-6 col-md-1 col-sm-1"><a href="#">Page 6</a></li>
        <li class=" col-lg-1 col-xs-6 col-md-1 col-sm-1"><a href="#">Page 7</a></li>
        <li class=" col-lg-1 col-xs-6 col-md-1 col-sm-1"><a href="#">Page 8</a></li>
        <li class="col-xs-push-1">
                <form class="navbar-form my-search " role="search">
                <div class="input-group ">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Search">
                   <div class="input-group-btn">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                   </div>
                 </div>
            </form>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Afsan Abdulali Gujarati**, I think for what I understand here, you want the xs view menu text to all stay on the right in one vertical line.
To stop the text wrapping around below the image. The image being responsive is full width of the col-xs-6. But it looks like you are trying or meaning to have the image the same height of the text links on the right.
Hopefully the way it lines up now is ok.

Have a look at this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0m0w4s04/)**.

All I did here was to add `padding-bottom:200px;` to the `li`tht holds the image.
See if this does what you want.

```
.keepclear{
    padding-bottom:200px;
}
```

**Added**
To remove any padding around a image in a navbar add this to your custom css to override Bootstrap css classes.

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
 }
```

Comment: Ohh, No. Maybe I explained it incorrectly, but there is no issues with the pattern or anything. Right now there is a text but eventually I'll replace them with images (the page1, page2, page3 .. etc). The concern is regarding the padding around the image. If you look at the image you'll see a grey padding, I want get rid of that and force the image to occupy the whole area both in large screen and mobile screen. 
I hope I've explained it correctly. Thank you for the response.

Comment: I have add a update to my post above that will remove any padding around the image.

Comment: Thank you so much :) That would help